# Of what layer is socket a concept?

Tags: transport-protocol, layer4

In network layer, IP address is a concept.

In transport layer, port is a concept. Is socket a concept of transport layer? If not, what is the corresponding concept to socket in transport layer? Of what layer is socket a concept?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Sockets are a TCP (transport layer) concept (there is also the off-topic programming concept of sockets which is clearly explained on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/152863/3745413)). [RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793)_ explains:

> Multiplexing:
>
> To allow for many processes within a single Host to use TCP
> communication facilities simultaneously, the TCP provides a set of
> addresses or ports within each host. Concatenated with the network and
> host addresses from the internet communication layer, this forms a
> **socket**. A pair of **sockets** uniquely identifies each connection. That
> is, a **socket** may be simultaneously used in multiple connections.
>
> The binding of ports to processes is handled independently by each
> Host. However, it proves useful to attach frequently used processes
> (e.g., a "logger" or timesharing service) to fixed **sockets** which are
> made known to the public. These services can then be accessed through
> the known addresses. Establishing and learning the port addresses of
> other processes may involve more dynamic mechanisms.
>
> Connections:
>
> The reliability and flow control mechanisms described above require
> that TCPs initialize and maintain certain status information for each
> data stream. The combination of this information, including **sockets**,
> sequence numbers, and window sizes, is called a connection. Each
> connection is uniquely specified by a pair of **sockets** identifying its
> two sides.
>
> When two processes wish to communicate, their TCP's must first
> establish a connection (initialize the status information on each
> side). When their communication is complete, the connection is
> terminated or closed to free the resources for other uses.
>
> Since connections must be established between unreliable hosts and
> over the unreliable internet communication system, a handshake
> mechanism with clock-based sequence numbers is used to avoid erroneous
> initialization of connections.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89708/discussion-on-answer-by-ron-maupin-of-what-layer-is-socket-a-concept).